# Spring Data mongodb converting empty array may be slow

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Short question:
Why does a mongodb query via spring-data MongoTemplate is slower when my entity contains an empty array ?

Long question:

I'm currently working on an application running on Spring 4.0.0 MVC backed by a MongoDB database.

The relevant part of my pom.xml is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the version of the transitively loaded java driver for mongo is 2.11.4.

And now, my problem.

One of my domain entity is as follow:

```
@Document
public class Team extends IdentifiableEntity{
    private List<String> skills = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> tools = new ArrayList<>();
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

IdentifiableEntity is common superclass for all my entities:

```
public abstract class IdentifiableEntity {

    @Indexed
    protected String id;

    @Indexed
    protected String name;

    @CreatedDate
    private DateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private DateTime lastModified;

    // also getters and setters
}
```

In my DAO I use MongoTemplate to interact with MongoDB, using basic queries.

On my development workstation, I'm forced to used an old 2.0.9 version of MongoDB because it's running an old Windows XP 32bits and I've no choice to change this at the moment. Tomcat version is 7.0.41.0 and Java version is 1.7.0_45. Processor is an old Celeron G1610 with 3Go of RAM (heavily charged because running netbeans, redmine, jenkins and a bunch of resource-eating-tools).
There were no sensible problem when I tested my code on this workstation.

I recently deployed my app on a demo platform running an old RHEL 5 unix, but using the last version (2.4.9) of MongoDB. Tomcat version is 7.0.52 and Java version is 1.7.0_51-b13. Everything is still 32 bits. Server is a VM using one Core of an Intel Xeon and 3Go of RAM.
And there begin the problems. When I try to load an entity of the "Team" class, it takes very very long. Around 80 seconds. For one record. I added a lot of logs messages and I was able to determine where I thought was the problem, and it should be in these lines:

File: "org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java"
Around line 1995:

```
private class ReadDbObjectCallback<T> implements DbObjectCallback<T> {

        private final EntityReader<? super T, DBObject> reader;
        private final Class<T> type;

        public ReadDbObjectCallback(EntityReader<? super T, DBObject> reader, Class<T> type) {
            Assert.notNull(reader);
            Assert.notNull(type);
            this.reader = reader;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public T doWith(DBObject object) {
            if (null != object) {
                maybeEmitEvent(new AfterLoadEvent<T>(object, type));
            }
1995 >>>    T source = reader.read(type, object);
            if (null != source) {
                maybeEmitEvent(new AfterConvertEvent<T>(object, source));
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be in the "reader.read()" method.

I continued my exploration and found out that the problem only appears when one my two List property is empty. If there are objects saved in these fields, my query are super-fast-as-normal. If one of them is empty, then it's super-slow (around 80 seconds).

Although I can't be sure, it seems the problem was already there on my workstation, but less sensible. Logs show that there is some latency at the same spot, but much less (around 150ms, which is much more than needed).

Moreover, it appears that the SAME problem appears with other entities having empty arrays as properties.

Do you have any kind of idea of why my query are slow when looking for records with empty arrays ?

Comment: Any chance you quantify "super slow" a little? You seem to have done deep investigations as you have spotted `ReadDbObjectCallback` to be the bottleneck. Care to share the details so that we can check what it is we can improve?

Comment: Sorry, I quantified if but it was not very visible in the paragraph where I describe my deployment environment. "Super slow" is around 80 seconds. (I edited my original message to make the timing more visible)

Comment: No idea about your issue, very strange. But IdentifiableEntity -> good idea to add createdBy and updatedBy fields too